# GLSL 2D Rounded corners

Tags: opengl, glsl, rounded-corners

I want to add some black outline to my game screen to make it look like the corners are rounded.
This is the effect I want to achieve: 
[image: rounded corners]

I figured this effect was probably quite easy to create using a shader, instead of drawing a giant bitmap on top of everything.

Can someone help me with the GLSL shader code for this effect? I have 0 experience with shaders and was unable to find anything like this on the internet.

Comment: My game is programmed using libGDX in Java by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat my shader now works. I've improved the performance and made it look smoothed.

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_screenOffset;

uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;
const float max = pow(0.2, 4);

void main()
{
    vec2 pos = (gl_FragCoord.xy - u_screenOffset) / u_resolution;

    float vignette = pos.x * pos.y * (1.-pos.x) * (1.-pos.y);

    vec4 color = texture2D(u_sampler2D, v_texCoord0) * v_color;
    color.rgb = color.rgb * smoothstep(0, max, vignette);

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Set the uniforms as follows in the resize event of libGDX:

```
shader.begin();
shader.setUniformf("u_resolution", viewport.getScreenWidth(), viewport.getScreenHeight());
shader.setUniformf("u_screenOffset", viewport.getScreenX(), viewport.getScreenY());
shader.end();
```

This will make sure the shader works with viewports (only tested with FitViewport) aswell.

Answer (score 8):

I've accidentaly found a nice solution for this. Not exactly what you've asked for, but in fact it looks even better.

```
// RESOLUTION is a vec2 with your window size in pixels.
vec2 pos = fragCoord.xy / RESOLUTION;
// Adjust .2 (first pow() argument) below to change frame thickness.
if (pos.x * pos.y * (1.-pos.x) * (1.-pos.y) < pow(.2,4.))
    fragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
```

It gives following result:

[image]

If you don't like those thin lines, you can remove them just by upscaling the image. It can be done by adding this line:

```
// The .985 is 1/scale_factor. You can try to change it and see how it works.
// It needs to be adjusted if you change frame thickness.
pos = (pos - .5) * .985 + .5;
```

[image]

---

While this effect looks good, it may be smarter to add just a faint shadow instead.
It's easy to implement using the same equation: `pos.x * pos.y * (1.-pos.x) * (1.-pos.y)`
The value of it ranges from `0.0` at window edges to `0.5^4` in the center.
You can use some easy math to do a shadow that becomes more thick closer to the window edge.
[Here is an example of how it may look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1qMH.png)
<sup>(A screenshot from [Duality](http://ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-35/?action=preview&uid=39241), my entry for Ludum Dare 35.)</sup>

Comment: Is there any way to apply some sort of AA to this effect? Thanks for the quick response btw, much appreciated. GotDownvotedFeelsBadMan

Comment: @kwantuM Yes it is. Try to do it yourself. It follows the same principle as the last advice in my answer.

Comment: I'll try implement it tomorrow, thanks for the help. I'll post a comment if I get stuck :)

Comment: I've improved your answer to be smoothed and not use 'if' because it causes performance issues.

Comment: @kwantuM That's good. But why you think that `if` causes performance issuses? All references that I could find say that `if` may execute both branches and discard one of them leading to performance loss, but it shouldn't affect this code too much.